# How to create an Android ActionBar in React Native?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, react-native

I would create an react native action bar in android like this:

[image]

Is there a way or a good example for do this with react native? I didn't found anything about this. I mean the 3 tabs.

Comment: Like this? https://github.com/AlbertBrand/react-native-android-tablayout

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what i was looking for.